# 403 error when scrapying this website

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website

this website returns `Error, query failed` in the body. then I click on `Find USED` tab. then I click search to get the result. the search button is actually making a post reqeust and get the data.

This is my spider:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield self.make_requests_from_url(url)

    def make_requests_from_url(self, url):
        return Request(url,cookies={'PHPSESSID':'0a94ce3bf2484d5102a047b86f5b6c17','__utm':'154876456.1461047540.1397668365.1397668365.1397668365.1',', callback=self.page_parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        print sel
```

I got this response:

```
2014-04-16 21:04:27+0300 [XXX] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <POST http://website> (referer: None)
```

what am I doing wrong please?

I analysed the request when I clicked the search button and this is the request

```
http://www.autodealer.ae/plugins/ad/buy.php?q=used+cars+dubai



User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: PHPSESSID=0a94ce3bf2484d5102a047b86f5b6c17;
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 131
```

what am i doing wrong?

or how to crawl that website please?

am I doing wrong on my spider?

Comment: There is a login on the site -- do you need to be logged in to get search results?

Comment: @ToddCurry no you can get the data without the loggin. just try to click on the `Find USED` tab then click search so you got the result

Answer (score 1):

The site requires authentication of some sorts and you are providing a fake `PHPSESSID` cookie with your request object. Your Python code should authenticate first and **then** keep sending request to the site.

-------- EDITED ----------

Posting to that URL causes a 403 error.

$ curl -X POST "**SITE EDITED**"

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
 <html><head>
 <title>403 Forbidden</title>
 </head><body>
 <h1>Forbidden</h1>
 <p>You don't have permission to access /plugins/ad/buy.php
  on this server.</p>
 <p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
    error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

 </p>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: so you suggest that I log in from my spider. then I make another request but the same data. right? However, I told you that you can get the data without being logged in. If you want try it please. You can click on the search button and get the results.

Comment: If authentication is not required then don't send cookies like `PHPSESSID`. That may lead the site to think that you're trying to make an authenticated request.

Comment: I tried to send the cookies using the official cookies middleware but keep getting that 403 http error

Comment: Do not send the cookies, those cookies are used for some authentication purposes and you are not authenticating your spider with the site.

Comment: so what should I do? I make just a post request, empty from any data or cookies and I keep getting that http error

Comment: just eddited the answer, seems that the site do requires authentication

Comment: pleaes try it yourself. and try to click on the search button to believe me. you can have the results without being logged in

Comment: I just send a request to the URL in your example using curl and got another 403 (HTTP code for Forbidden) , either the site requires authentication or your URL is wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50820/discussion-between-yorodm-and-user2208349)

Comment: +1 to you, please could you remove the site from your answer, thanks for your understanding